# remove carriage return in Openssl command from windows

Tags: batch-file, openssl, tr

I want to remove the carriage return from my output file when running OpenSSL command.

Here is my code and I am getting error tr is not recognised since this is UNIX command. But how can i convert into batch command within Openssl command link

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K "C:\cat aes_key.txt" -iv "C:\aes_iv.txt" -in plaintext.xml | openssl enc -e -base64 | tr -d '\n' > encrypted.txt
```

Comment: Maybe tr.exe from [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) could help you?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `|tr -d '\n' > encrypted.txt` with a repl.bat command

```
|repl "\r" "" xm > encrypted.txt
```

This assumes that it is a CR and not a CRLF which is the normal Windows line ending.  if you want to replace CRLF then use `"\r\n"`

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Comment: the link is not opening.. can you please paste the code from repl?

Comment: I got the code now.. Can you please tell me what is xm in your command? Is it xml content as variable? If so in the existing shell script (someone written earlier) they are not passing any variable.. So can I remove this xm from my command?

Comment: xm are switches for repl.bat and not related to XML.  Run `repl /?` for the help screen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support. I have found a solution by vbscript. I have written below vbscript and save it as vbs file and pass the file name and path that needs to be CRLF remvoed

```
Const ForReading = 1 
Const ForWriting = 2 
strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0) 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading) 
WScript.Echo "Checking"
strText = objFile.ReadAll 
objFile.Close 
strNewText = Replace(strText, chr(010), "") ' chr(010) = line feed chr(013) = carriage return 

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting) 
WScript.Echo strNewText
objFile.WriteLine strNewText 
objFile.Close
```